# Firestore querying by due date for items due today

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Am having troubles querying my database for items due today.

```
_firestore
    .collectionGroup('tasks')
    .where('dueDate', isEqualTo: DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day))
```

since firestore save the time as well, this query only returns when the time is 12:00, essentially when the day has started. how do i make it work for anytime during that day?

am also hoping for a library i can use to check if today, tomorrow, this week etc